# If the acceleration is constant, does it lie on a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

The Calculus 3 book Apostle Volume 1 has a group of questions I don't quite know how to approach. It says that for the next two statements about a curve traced out by a particle moving in 3-space to give a proof or exhibit a counter example.

---

(a) If the acceleration is constant, the curve lies in a plane.

---

(b) If the velocity is perpendicular to the acceleration, the curve lies in a plane.

How do I approach these problems? What does it mean to lie in a plane? A solution to either would be appreciated as it would help me understand better.

Answer (score 1):

If acceleration is constant, then the object takes a parabolic path through space (see constant gravitational acceleration), which thus lies on a plane.

If velocity is perpendicular to acceleration, then the object travels in a circle (see this video for a full explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3u53wVeWfA)
For this second case, you can imagine swinging a ball on a string in a circle over your head. Acceleration is always directed inwards, perpendicular to the velocity of the ball, which is tangent to the curve of the circle.

Comment: oh ok thanks the video helped!